# Unable to install tidyverse set of packages

Tags: r, tidyverse

I opened up the RStudio app and attempted to install the tidyverse package. I received the following series of error messages:

```
* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'callr' ...
** package 'callr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'processx' 3.5.3 is being loaded, but >= 3.6.1 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/callr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'knitr' ...
** package 'knitr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.30 is being loaded, but >= 0.39 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'knitr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/knitr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'bslib'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/bslib'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bslib’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'tidyselect'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/tidyselect'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyselect’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'gtable'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/gtable'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gtable’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'gargle'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/gargle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gargle’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'forcats'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/forcats'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘forcats’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'hms'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/hms'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'pillar'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/pillar'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'rvest'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rvest'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'stringr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/stringr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'hms' is not available for package 'progress'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/progress'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘progress’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'bslib', 'knitr', 'stringr' are not available for package 'rmarkdown'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rmarkdown'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'lifecycle', 'stringr' are not available for package 'broom'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/broom'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'lifecycle', 'pillar', 'tidyselect' are not available for package 'dbplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/dbplyr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'lifecycle', 'tidyselect' are not available for package 'dtplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/dtplyr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dtplyr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'gtable', 'lifecycle' are not available for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'gargle', 'lifecycle', 'pillar' are not available for package 'googledrive'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/googledrive'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googledrive’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'gargle', 'googledrive', 'lifecycle' are not available for package 'googlesheets4'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/googlesheets4'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googlesheets4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'broom', 'tidyselect' are not available for package 'modelr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/modelr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'callr', 'knitr', 'lifecycle', 'rmarkdown' are not available for package 'reprex'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/reprex'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'broom', 'dbplyr', 'dtplyr', 'forcats', 'ggplot2', 'googledrive', 'googlesheets4', 'hms', 'modelr', 'pillar', 'reprex', 'rvest', 'stringr' are not available for package 'tidyverse'
* removing 'C:/Users/Aaron.Hodges/OneDrive - Serco/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/tidyverse'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can somebody help me resolve this issue. I have no idea what all this means.

I have tried to update RTools but that did not work.

Comment: Have you tried after updating R? It appears that your current version is 4.0.x.

Comment: Don't get overwhelmed by errors, just look for the first one: `'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required`. You need to update your `rlang` package. So do `install.packages("rlang")`, and then try again.

Comment: But also Phil has a good point. R version 4.0 is about 2 years old, the current version is 4.3.2, soon to be 4.3.3. You might want to update R and then update all your packages to take advantage of some of the nice new features.